# How to make mayonnaise hang down in blender 2.92

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, sculpting

I am creating a 3d birger in blender 2.92 using cycles renderer. I want the mayonnaise in the burger to hang down like real life but I don't know how. Should I try to model or sculpt it? Please help.

Thanks in advance.[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add reference images

Comment: Hello :). Both Subdivision Surface modeling and Sculpting should work. It's up to you what approach to take.

Comment: So sculpting will make a good and faster result?

Comment: @JachymMichal Thanks a lot! Now my burger eally looks nice and real.

Comment: One nice trick for doing this when you don't feel very creative is to use the Proportional Editing tool and set the Falloff Influence to Random. Then grab all the vertices making up the edge loop at the outer perimeter of the mayo spread object, and then pull them all downward. They will follow to  different extents, and might more closely resemble a real phenomenon than you'd get from manually sculpting.